# what's the best way to use command line applications in a docker environment?

Tags: docker, compilation, continuous-integration, docker-compose

For composing services that are exposed over the network through ports (`-p 5000:5000`) docker provides all kinds of help (e.g. [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)).
What I'm looking for is a way to provide certain **binary applications** as a service in a docker container. Examples would be:

- compiler (e.g. gcc)
- generators (e.g. for protocol buffers)
- ...

## running a single command

my current approach is to have a small shell script that passes parameters an takes care of mapping the current directory:

```
runbox(){
  current_dir=${PWD##*/}
  docker run --rm -it \
    -v ${PWD}:/home/dev/${current_dir} \
    -w /home/dev/${current_dir} \
    box:latest \
    /bin/bash -c "$@"
}
```

using it looks like this:

```
runbox "g++ --version"
```

compared to running locally:

```
g++ --version
```

## composing multiple commands

Now let's say I have *n* such service, how do I *compose* them in a way that all of them can be used in another container (e.g. running on a ci)?

```
                             Services running
                             in Docker containers
+---------------------+
|                     |       +---------+
| CI Docker Container +-----> |  gcc    |
|                     |       +---------+
|                     |
|     make            +-----> +---------+
|                     |       |  protoc |
|                     |       +---------+
+----------------+----+
                 |            +---------+
                 +----------> |  clang  |
                              +---------+
```

what about the overhead of calling a command *very* often?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the CI gives you access to a docker engine (via socket or port) it shouldn't matter if it's run in a container or not.

If you're using make and running project tasks from a container, you might be interested in [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/). It's a tool designed to something like you're describing. You define the images, containers, mounts, etc that you use to build your project.

You can run each task like you would run a make target (`dobi <taskname>`). You could have one task for gcc, protoc, clang, etc.